# PHP - Delete multiple rows via Checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code, which works to a certain degree:

```
if(isset($_POST['remove'])) {
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $passcode = $_POST['passcode'];

    $sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM admin 
            WHERE username = '" . $user . "' 
            and passcode ='".md5($passcode)."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($count==0) {
        echo "Invalid Credentials";
    } else {

        include 'config.php';
        $cnt=array();
        $listCheck = "'" .implode("','", $_POST['checkbox']) . "'";
        $sql6 = "DELETE FROM `customer` WHERE `name` IN ($listCheck)";
        $delete = mysqli_query ($conn,$sql6);
    }
```

Issue is, it only deletes 1 of the selected rows. How do I modify the code so it deletes ALL of the selected rows?

```
<input type="submit" name="remove" class="btn2" value="Delete Selected">
<div>
<?php
$query1 = "SELECT `name` FROM `customer` ORDER BY `name` ASC ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);

echo "<table>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' id='checkbox[]' value=" . $row['name'] . "></td>";
echo"</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<br>";
?>
</div>
```

Comment: result of var_dump($_POST['checkbox']) ?

Comment: Check how many times for loop is looping.

Comment: Show us the HTML, specifically the `<form>` containing the Checkboxes in question

Comment: what is the count in `$cnt` variable.

Comment: @RiggsFolly asked you to post your HTML over an hour ago; you failed to do that. How are we to know if that isn't failing? You're still at it with the answers given but we're not seeing an accepted answer.

Comment: `md5($passcode)`? I sure hope for your sake that this isn't a live site; you will get hacked.

Comment: Seems to me that you're only responding to answers instead of comments up here. Well, suit yourself. This could be such an easy fix, it could even be silly, wishing you well with this; good luck.

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use one query to delete all records without the pain of for loop

```
 include 'config.php';
 $array = $_POST['checkbox'];
 $listCheck = "'" . implode("','", $array) . "'";
 echo $sql6 = "DELETE FROM `customer` WHERE `name` IN ($listCheck)";
 $delete = mysqli_query ($conn,$sql6);
```

Also there is issue in this code. Replace the below line with your code

```
echo "<td><input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' id='checkbox[]' value='" . $row['name'] . "'></td>";
```

Comment: Can you print the `$sql6 `?

Comment: You are using the `LIKE` operator instead of `IN`. Also can you `var_dump($_POST['checkbox'])`

Comment: why are you using the `for loop`. I have added the answer to remove the loop. Please paste the var_dump of `$_POST['checkbox']`

Comment: `implode` shouldn't take too much time.

Comment: @S.King Please replace the updated answer in else part of your code

Comment: did you change the `LIKE` to `IN`. Can you paste the query

Comment: @S.King The `var_dump()` output you are showing is nonsense!!!! For example `CUSTOMER1` is a ___9 byte string___ and your vardump is showing a **5 byte string. We cannot debug PSEUDO CODE**

Comment: Didn't $listCheck evaluate to array values?

Comment: @S.King Check this link i have created, your sql should be like this https://repl.it/HX0L

Comment: @S.King This is just for demonstration purposes. The array will contain your `$_POST['checkbox']`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142511/discussion-between-agam-banga-and-s-king).

Comment: @S.King can you paste the output of `$sql6`

Comment: @S.King there was issue in the html form, Please check the answer again

Answer (score 1):

better go with `foreach( $_POST['checkbox'] as $k => $v)`, it may not always be numbers and even if this way you do not have a loop for each possible in range but only for each selected checkbox.

Also have a look on prepared statements for SQL queries, you do not want to have possible injections.

Besides `LIKE` better be replaced by the exact comparison `=`.

Comment: "my code" will indeed not delete anything, it just provides the key and value of the list it iterates over… that you can then use to delete exactly what you need; anyways in this case the example of Agam is neat, solves the request and should be voted and marked by you ;)

Comment: of course, you wont have `$i` any more … you then have `$k` for key and `$v` for value of the list; maybe have a look into them e.g. with `print_r()` and discover the structure of your `$_POST` the same way, then you may begin to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
 include 'config.php';
 $array = $_POST['checkbox'];
 $listCheck = "";
 foreach($array as $arr) {
     $listCheck .= "'" . urldecode($arr) . "',";
 }
 $listCheck = substr(trim($listCheck), 0, -1);
 echo $sql6 = "DELETE FROM `customer` WHERE `name` IN ($listCheck)";
 $delete = mysqli_query ($conn,$sql6);
```

Comment: Does your `$row['name']` contain the full name?

Answer (score 1):

This is something that caught my eye

```
echo "<td><input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' id='checkbox[]' value" . $row['name'] . "></td>";
```

Should be

```
echo '<td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="'.$row['name'].'" ></td>';
```

The value of the checkbox is missing an =

Comment: Alright gotcha.
Using the users name in this situation might be risky.
What happens if more people go by the same name?

Always use an ID for this type of situation. If your table does not have one. Add it. This will fix your problem with spaces in names as well

Comment: Glad to hear it's solved. This could have easily been avoided if you used ID's tho ;-)